# Do action for each register without ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to determine which registers are about to expire. I have half of the script which shows ones that are close to expiring but I need to save the final date:

```
declare @FechaIngreso datetime --Variable to determinate begin
declare @FechaEgreso datetime --Variable End
declare @DiasExp Int --Days before Expire
set @DiasExp = 10
select @FechaIngreso = GETDATE() --Get the actual date
select @FechaEgreso = (select top 1 FEC_FINA from FA_DDERI where (DATEDIFF (dd, @FechaIngreso,FEC_FINA) ) = @DiasExp ) --heres the thing I select just 1 with top 1 cause I need save the final date to comparate the dates
select * from FA_DDERI where FEC_FINA = @FechaEgreso 
select  COUNT(*) from  FA_DDERI where  FEC_FINA = @FechaEgreso --this tell me how many lines get the condition
```

I need a condition like the following:

```
if (select FEC_FINA from FA_DDERI where (DATEDIFF (dd, @FechaIngreso,FEC_FINA) ) = @DiasExp)
 print 'The Reso Will Expire'
 break
else
 continue
print'Any Reso will Expire'
```

The tables only have 1 unique column and its is not an identity column

Is there a control statement to check every line in the database to prove the condition?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

```
 SELECT FEC_FINA, 
        CASE 
          WHEN DATEDIFF (dd, @FechaIngreso,FEC_FINA) ) = @DiasExp THEN 'The Reso Will Expire' 
          ELSE 'Any Reso will Expire' 
        END AS resultcol
 FROM FA_DDERI
```